# How to Replace Backslash at End of String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace a string in Python in a pandas column, from 'EXAMPLE\' to blank, the code I used is below:

`df[<column_name>].str.replace('EXAMPLE\\', '')`

however I would get the error "re.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 7"

If I do `df[<column_name>].str.replace('EXAMPLE', '')` it works completely fine, anyway to do this?

Comment: `str.replace` can never raise an `re.error`. Are you actually using Pandas or something?

Comment: You're getting `re.error` but using `str.replace`?

Comment: Yea it's on a pandas column

Comment: `pandas.Series.str.replace` is an entirely different thing from `str.replace`, with completely different behavior. It's important to be clear up front about what you're actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `pandas.Series.str.replace` does regex substitution, not string replacement. It delegates to `re.sub`, not `str.replace`. If you want to use non-regex mode, pass `regex=False`:

```
df[whatever].str.replace('EXAMPLE\\', '', regex=False)
```

Alternatively, you could use a valid regex. The regex engine does its own backslash processing, so you need to use a raw string literal to avoid Python's own backslash processing:

```
df[whatever].str.replace(r'EXAMPLE\\', '')
```

See the [`pandas.Series.str.replace` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for other arguments and more examples.